# What does visible mean for Ranorex exactly

Tags: ranorex

Visible in the context of UI-testautomation can mean two different things:

1. Visible anywhere on the website. You can see it immediately or after you scroll
2. Visible in the viewport, which means, that you can see the element without scrolling.

In the [Ranorex documentation](http://www.ranorex.com/Documentation/Ranorex/html/P_Ranorex_Adapter_Visible.htm) the definition isn't clear regarding this. So what is in Ranorex the exact definition for "visible"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visible attribute itself just means that it is possible in general to bring the element to the visible region. If the visible attribute of a parent element is set to false it might also not be possible to make the element itself visible.

Comment: Ranorex official support told me, that this answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

It means that visible anywhere on website.
It means if you get visible true but cannot click you need to scroll first.

Comment: there no such a thing like an html-attibute 'visible'. And Ranorex is running also for desktop-applications, not only websites.

Comment: you are right but what i meant was is that it can be visible but you still need to scroll

Comment: It is a little bit tricky. The visible property is true if the element is visible on the viewport. If the element is not visible on the viewport, the visible property is set to false. If the element is visible on the viewport, but another application hides the element, the visible property is also set to true. Additionally, if you move the section of the browser window containing the element to a region outside the visible screen, the visible attribute is also set to true. In that case you can also use the action ensure visible to make the element visible on the screen.